# 共有パソコンにおける、Pythonパッケージのユーザー管理フォルダへのインストール

Tags: python, macos

共有パソコンにおけるPythonライブラリのインストール時の設定について質問させてください。OSはMac OS X 10.9.5です。

Python3.4が`/opt/local/bin/python3.4`にインストールされているのですが、必要なライブラリが入っておらず、自分で追加したいと考えております。

まず、ターミナルで`pip`を使ってライブラリを追加しようとしましたが、"command not found"というエラーが出てインストールできません。
pipはPython 3.4では標準のパッケージ管理だと理解していたので、pipをアクティベートしようとしましたが、失敗しました。

次に、必要なライブラリの`.tar.gz`をダウンロードし、`python3.4 setup.py install`を試しましたが、`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/`に書き込み権限がない旨のエラーが出てインストールできませんでした。

さらに、`python3.4 setup.py install --home=DIRECTORY`も試しましたが、

> You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not on
>   PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.

というエラーで失敗しました。

そこで、何か設定を変更することで、アクセス権限のあるフォルダ(管理者権限を必要としないユーザー領域)にライブラリだけインストールしたいと思うのですが、どのような設定をすれば良いのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--user`オプションをつけることでインストールできるはずです。

```
python3.4 setup.py install --user
```

のようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

Python3 の pip は `pip3` というコマンド名だと思います。
なんらかの事情でインストールされていない場合は、[ensurepipモジュール](http://docs.python.jp/3/library/ensurepip.html)でインストールできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法も試したのですが、`pip3`としても`pip3.4`としても、「コマンドがない」旨のエラーが出ています。本当はpipが使えた方が便利なのですが...

Comment: virtual environmentを使ってはどうでしょう？
`$ python3 -m venv my_venv`
`$ source my_venv/bin/activate`でpipも使えるようになると思うのですが。

Comment: 確かにこれで動きますね。私はいまいち仕組みがわかっていませんが...汗